# How to run PHPUnit test using browser?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am new in PHPUnit and i am required to run the test using browser and save the result in xml format.
But every time when i run this code, i got following error:

FatalErrorException: Error: Interface 'PHPUnit_Framework_Test' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php line 83

My code looks like this:

```
 require_once '/var/www/Drillsight/app/autoload.php';
 require_once "PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php";
 require_once "PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php";

 $run_command = new PHPUnit_TextUI_Command;
 $run_command ->run(array('phpunit', '--log-junit', 'results.xml', 'MyPHPUnitTest.php'),true);
```

Can anybody help in this matter?
Any other recommendation options will be highly appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Do it really need to be runned in a browser?

I personally use a .bat file containing all my unit test like this

```
REM GEM_MECHANIC_TESTS

ECHO.
ECHO FILE : GEM_MECHANIC_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
CALL PHPUNIT %~DP0/../../../GENERAL_CONTROLER/TEST/GEM_MECHANIC_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
ECHO.


REM GEM_MECHANIC_INTERFACE_BUILDER_TESTS
ECHO.
ECHO FILE : HTML_GEM_MECHANIC_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
CALL PHPUNIT %~DP0/../../../GENERAL_CONTROLER/TEST/TEST_INTERFACE_BUILDER/HTML_GEM_MECHANIC_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
ECHO.
```

And run a command like this in my Xampp console:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler/script/temp_unit_test.bat >C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler/test_result.txt
```

Or if you want to do it automatically each night with a windows task:

Launch_xampp.bat

```
@echo off
tasklist | find /i "xampp-control.exe" && goto :eof

start /b "xampp-control.exe" "C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe"
```

launch_automatic_test.bat

```
@echo off

call %~DP0\launch_xampp.bat

call %~DP0\..\..\..\..\xampp_shell.bat

cls

call %~DP0\run_unit_test.bat > "%~DP0\..\test_result.txt"
```

The method don't matter as much as I export the result in a textfile and than use PHP to parse the output (you can just change the code a bit to produce XML).

```
public static function fetchTestResult(&$errorMessage){

$echoString = '';
$failure = false;
$fileContent = '';
$errorMessage = '';

$dbManager = GeneralDbManager::getInstance();

if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/test_result.txt')) {

    @$fileContent = file(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/test_result.txt');

    if ($fileContent === false){

        $errorMessage = $dbManager->getErrorMessage('UNIT_TEST_RESULT_LOG_ERR', "An error happened while reading the unit tests results log."); 
    }
    else{

        unlink(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/test_result.txt');

        if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/script/temp_unit_test.bat')) {

            unlink(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/script/temp_unit_test.bat');
        }

        $echoString = HtmlTagBuilder::createCustomTextArea("TA_UNIT_TEST_RESULT", TextAlign::ALIGN_LEFT, false, 1100, 500);

        foreach ($fileContent as $line){

            if (StringManager::stringStartWith($line, "FILE :")){

                $failure = false;

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::TITLE_LINE);
            }
            elseif (StringManager::stringStartWith($line, "time:")){

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::WARNING_LINE);
            }
            elseif (StringManager::stringStartWith($line, "OK (")){

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::SUCCESS_LINE);
            }
            elseif ((StringManager::stringStartWith($line, "There ") and strpos($line, "failure") !== false)
                or $failure === true){

                $failure = true;

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::ERROR_LINE);
            }
            elseif (strpos(strtolower($line), "failure") !== false){

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::ERROR_LINE);
            }
            else{

                $echoString .= HtmlTagBuilder::addLineCustomTextArea($line, CustomTextAreaLine::REGULAR_LINE);  
            }
        }

        $echoString .= '</DIV><br><br>';
    }

}
else{
    $errorMessage = $dbManager->getErrorMessage('UNIT_TEST_NO_RESULT_LOG_ERR', "You must run the unit test and generate the test log before displaying it.");
}

return $echoString;
}
```